# Using Cedar Planks for shower ceiling

Tags: bathroom, ceiling, woodworking, caulking

I have an old house that came with stained wooden planks for the lower bathroom shower ceiling. I recently tore down the ceiling in order to fix a drain leakage in the shower above. Now im looking to redo (reinstall) the ceiling using brand new wooden planks.

I got thin aromatic cedar plans from home-depot. They came in a box and they inter-lock with each other. After the ceiling planks are all installed i planned on doing additional caulking and then painting it with paint + gloss coating (to further prevent moisture from entering thru).

[Link](http://www.homedepot.com/p/1-4-in-x-3-3-4-in-x-48-in-100-Aromatic-Eastern-Red-Cedar-Planking-36422/205667315) to the cedar slats im planning to use.

**Questions**

- Does anybody see any outstanding or possible future issues with this nearly complete DIY project (i still need to sand this down and paint it)?
- Also, I will probably add an extra layer of gloss paint for water/moisture protection. Will this cause any issues, like trapping undesirable moisture above the wooden planks?

Thank you for reading. All feedback is welcome!

**Updated**

I have installed the cedar plans (despite them being very thin and warped in some places). I used nails, liquid nails, and finished with latex/silicone caulking along all the joints.

[image]
[image][image][image]

Comment: What was behind the slats of the original shower and what condition were they in barring what the leaking shower above did to them?

Comment: Behind (above) the slats was nothing. It is just open plumbing, ducts, etc. I am able to see the floor of the bathroom above. The condition was pretty dusty, some few dead insects, cob webs, possibly old water stains (white stuff).

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would sand out the flaws from liquid nails, etc. and stain/varnish. I would add some cedar details other place in the bathroom as well. Finish with clear silicone II at edges and joints. Looks nice!

Comment: I started with clear silicone, then i stopped because i realized i wont be able to paint over them.

Comment: Right. Silicone is the very last step. I was suggesting stain or varnish because the wood is so good looking. Makes the bathroom look warm and cozy.